# PSET 3 - Tideman - locking pairs - I can't see what is missing?

Tags: c, cs50

i have debugged a million times and i feel i have tried it all, but it still gives back error message:

:( lock_pairs locks all pairs when no cycles
lock_pairs did not lock all pairs
:) lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle
:) lock_pairs skips middle pair if it creates a cycle

I have tried rewriting it in different ways also, and i cant seem to get it to work(i dont know what needs to be fixed hehe). When i run it in debug50, it does lock all pairs when no cycle, and it handles pairs that creates a cycle also. So why does my code not work? Thanks!

```
for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        if (locked[pairs[i].loser][j] == true)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < candidate_count; k++)
            {
                if (locked[k][pairs[i].winner] == true)
                {
                    
                    printf("locked[%i][%i] is false", pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser);
                    locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = false;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("locked[%i][%i] is true", pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser);
                    locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
                }
            }
        break;    
        }
        else
        {
            printf("locked[%i][%i] is true", pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser);
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }
    }
}

return;
```

Comment: Is it possible that the "sorted pairs" could be faulty and returns an array that does not contain the winner by decreasing order?  Even though, it goes through the check50 test?

Comment: There are a few nuances to `lock_pairs()` that control when to check for a cycle. One implementation is [PSET3 Tideman](https://paste.opensuse.org/96835475). Good for 1-week. Look it over and see if that helps.

Comment: Also, look at the right-column under **Related** -- there are a number of additional answers related to Tideman.

Comment: please post a [mre] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to give thanks to you guys! I figured it out in the end looking into the PSET 3 Tideman. Thanks for the help!